# Is a question asking if a certain type of software is legal under a specific legal system on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question, questions, migration

I'm moderator of crypto-SE and wonder if [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/99603/555) would be on-topic if migrated to Law-SE. The meat of it is:

> Is it legal to develop a cipher-breaker software/algorithm? What about it's legality in India?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know next to nothing about cipher-breaker software or algorithms so I can't say for certain, but questions asking whether something is lawful or not are definitely on-topic here - as long as they're not asking for specific legal advice.

Answer (score 2):

While **on topic** we require some minimum standards to explain what the problem is. [The migrated question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/79281/is-it-legal-to-develop-a-cipher-breaker-software) is lacking most of the facts that would show if it is legal or illegal.

Comment: Sorry about that. I wish the OP can add details.